Vaadin Flow: Cannot resolve symbol 'ContactFormEvent' when trying to implements events
I've been trying to implement the events in my contact form, however I get the 'Cannot resolve symbol 'ContactFormEvent'' when trying to implement the following methods:

    public static class SaveEvent extends ContactFormEvent {
        SaveEvent(ContactForm source, Contact contact) {
            super(source, contact);
        }
    }

    public static class DeleteEvent extends ContactFormEvent {
        DeleteEvent(ContactForm source, Contact contact) {
            super(source, contact);
        }

    }

    public static class CloseEvent extends ContactFormEvent {
        CloseEvent(ContactForm source) {
            super(source, null);
        }
    }

Additonally, I've been dealing with the reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that CloseEvent conforms to ComponentEvent<?> error for the following methods.
    public Registration addDeleteListener(ComponentEventListener<DeleteEvent> listener) {
        return addListener(DeleteEvent.class, listener);
    }

    public Registration addSaveListener(ComponentEventListener<SaveEvent> listener) {
        return addListener(SaveEvent.class, listener);
    }
    public Registration addCloseListener(ComponentEventListener<CloseEvent> listener) {
        return addListener(CloseEvent.class, listener);
    }

What could be the solution here? I am running out of ideas, it seems like it has to do something with Vaadin's versioning, but I can't find any working solution.

Please add the code for ContactFormEvent

If I understood correctly, this is something that should be imported from Vaadin's library/maven dependency

That looks alot like a base class you have to write. If not, what "contact form" libary are you using (or more likely, what tutorial you are following)?

"If I understood correctly" Where does your understanding come from?

ContactFormEvent is not a Vaadin class, it's a custom class coming from somewhere else. You'll need to look into where you got that example code from.
